# Meshlab Poisson Blob and not allinged

Tags: blob, poisson, meshlab

I am trying to use Meshlab to calculate the volume of a pile of stone. M
y issue is that each time I use the poisson surface reconstruction I get a huge "blob" protruding out from the bottom of the model. This happens on every model I input.

My model is coming as a mesh directly from Agisoft. Note in the picture the blob and model are misaligned to the original model as well.

[image]